# Use php preg_match_all() to capture uuids followed by @ character

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-match-all

how to use `preg_match_all()` to get `1a1a-1a1a` and `2B2B2-B2`in the following string :

```
$string  = 'Hello @1a1a-1a1a and @2B2B2-B2 too';
```

my aim is to capture every `@` followed by a uuid.

i tried :

```
preg_match_all("/@(.*)/", $string, $matches);
preg_match_all("/@.*?/U", $string, $matches);
preg_match_all("/@([^\"]+)/si", $a, $matches);
```

but can't make it

Comment: Use `preg_match_all("/@\K[\w-]+/", $a, $matches);`

Comment: Your regexs are too loose. You need to have the pattern stop at some point. You could use https://regex101.com/r/GDiZe7/1/ `@\S+` which will keep going until a whitespace is found.. or above regex should also work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `/(?<=@)[\w-]+/` pattern that match any string after `@`

```
preg_match_all("/(?<=@)[\w-]+/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

Output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1a1a-1a1a
    [1] => 2B2B2-B2
)
```

Check result in [demo](https://3v4l.org/AXKMF)

Answer (score 2):

The `@(.*)` regex matches a `@` and the greedily any 0 or more chars other than line break chars (i.e. the rest of the line). `/@.*?/U` is a  synonymous pattern, it is equal to `/@.*/`, the text after `@` just is not captured into a group. `@([^\"]+)` matches `@` and captures into Group 1 any one or more chars other than `"` and that will either match up to the first `"` or end of string if there is no `"`.

I suggest using

```
preg_match_all('~@\K[\w-]+~', $s, $matches)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bemQgO/1/). `@\K[\w-]+` will match `@` and `\K` will remove it from the match, and `[\w-]+` will match 1 or more word or `-` chars that will be returned.

To make the pattern a bit more restrictive, say, to only match  letters or digits after `@` that can be hyphen separated, you may use

```
'~@\K[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*~i'
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bemQgO/3). Here, `[A-Z0-9]+` matches 1 or more  alphanumeric chars and `(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*` will match 0 or more repetitions of a `-` followed with 1+ alphanumeric chars. `i` modifier will make the pattern case insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

Your regexes ar matching:

- `@(.*)` Matches @ and captures in a group any character 0+ times greedy including the space which will match all in your example
- `@.*?` Matches @ followed by any character 0+ times non greedy which will only match the `@`
- `@([^\"]+)` Matches @ and captures in a group matching not a `"` which will match all in your example

To capture every `@` followed by a uuid, you could use a [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) to list what you would allow to match and repeat that pattern preceded by a dash in a non capturing group 1+ times.

If you want to match the uuid only, you could capture the values in a capturing group.

`@([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/85xkAm/1/)

```
$string  = 'Hello @1a1a-1a1a and @2B2B2-B2 too';
preg_match_all("/@([a-zA-Z0-9]+(?:-[a-zA-Z0-9]+)+)/", $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

Result

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1a1a-1a1a
    [1] => 2B2B2-B2
)
```

[Demo php](https://3v4l.org/T20rq)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will catch everything after '@', no matter how many characters

preg_match_all("@(\w)*/", $string, $matches)